# how can i solve PyEnchant error in python 3.6.2?

Tags: python, pyenchant

```
import enchant
d = enchant.Dict("en_GB")
d.check("hello")
```

AttributeError: module 'enchant' has no attribute 'Dict'

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Any chance you have named some other module `enchant`? Maybe even the one with the code you've shown?